# Data return from axios cant be written to variable

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, axios

I want to get an data attribute from my axios post and write it to an local variable to reuse it.
If i console.log it inside the axios .then, tha data is set, if i write it to my variable and want to use it after, it is empty.

```
export default {
        data(){
        return {
          post:{},
          projectId: '',
          existingProjects: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addPost(){
            //check if project exists else create
            let uriProj = 'http://localhost:4000/projects/add';
            this.axios.post(uriProj, {
               projectName: this.post.project,
            }).then(response => this.projectId = response.data.data);
            console.log("project_id: "+this.projectId)
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Another Question:

Is this the right way if i want to reuse the id in another method?
My Goal is to first create a project if it is not already in my db, then i want to reuse the id of the created or returned project model to create a new customer in my db, if the customer already has the project with the id of this project, it shouldnt be added, if it is a new one it should be added.

Has this to be done in multiple requests or is there a simple method for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue you are seeing has to do with the asynchronous nature of network calls. When axios submits the post request it returns a Promise then the `addPost` function continues executing. So the `projectId` gets logged after it the initial value gets set, but before the network request completes. Everything inside the `then()` function executes once the network request has been completed so you can test by moving the console.log to be executed once the request is done. You could also output the value in the template so you can see it update `{{ projectId }}`

```
        this.axios.post(uriProj, {
           projectName: this.post.project,
        }).then(response => {
            this.projectId = response.data.data
            console.log("project_id: "+this.projectId)
        });
```

I would ideally recommend using the VueJS dev tools browser extension because it allows you to inspect the state of your Vue components without having to use `console.log` or add random echos to your template markup.

Answer (score 0):

@jfadich is correct. I recommend using `async/await` instead of `then`, it's more intuitive to read.

```
async addPost(){
    //check if project exists else create
    let uriProj = 'http://localhost:4000/projects/add';
    let resp = await this.axios.post(uriProj, {
       projectName: this.post.project,
    })
    this.projectId = resp.data.data
    console.log("project_id: "+this.projectId)
}
```